# MySQL INSERT INTO using SELECT with TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm using this code:

```
INSERT INTO table_b SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id = 'Example1';
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE id = 'Example1';
```

I want to move (or copy then delete) a data from from one table (Table_a) to another (Table_B)

But I have this error:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Because **Table_b** has a **TIMESTAMP** column in it, while **Table_a** don't.

How can I put a value on timestamp? Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the timestamp is first or last column, you can try with:

```
SELECT *, now() FROM ... or SELECT now(), * FROM ...
```

otherwise you have to provide all column names, as Gordon suggested

Comment: It worked! My timestamp is at the last column btw. Thank you very much. `SELECT *, now()` Worked.

Answer (score 2):

List the columns explicitly.  I think the error message is pretty clear, and when you use `insert`, yo should get in the habit of listing the columns:

```
insert into table_b(col1, . . . , coln)
    select col1, . . . coln
    from table_a
    where id = 'Example1';
```

Comment: @Potato . . . You need to put in only the columns that match.  Leave out the timestamp.